# Как реализовать такую горизонтальную линию?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать такую горизонтальную линию:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой код:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.line {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.line-left {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

.line-right {
  width: 20%; 
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
}

.line-right:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 140px solid green;
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div class="line-left">
    
  </div>
   <div class="line-right">
     
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: градиентами не проще ?

Comment: @MaximLensky подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать градиентами?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот так проще всего

```css
.gradient {
  height: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(115deg, hsl(30, 85%, 70%) 70%, hsl(0, 0%, 57%) 71%);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @kiskiskit отмечать решением не забываем